# printJobCompleted() no funciona

Tags: java, impresión

Necesito comprobar si la impresora terminó de imprimir lo que sea que se la haya mandando, encontre que con la interfaz PrintJobListener puedo hacer eso, pero el metodo más importante printJobCompleted() no funciona aunque el documento se haya imprimido, no recibe ningun evento, solo funciona printDataTransferCompleted(). [Este es un ejemplo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ListeningforPrintJobStatusChanges.htm)

Mi listener:

```
public class MyPrintJobListener implements PrintJobListener{

private boolean completed = false;
@Override
public void printDataTransferCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Transferecia de datos completada");

}

@Override
public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Impresion cancelada");

}

@Override
public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Impresion completada");
}

@Override
public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "No se pudo imprimir");
}

@Override
public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void printJobRequiresAttention(PrintJobEvent pje) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Mi metodo:

```
public void imprimir()  throws PrintException{
    String s = "ESTO ES UNA PRUEBA";
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    PrintService service =   PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    System.out.println("impresora: " + service);
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

    MyPrintJobListener listener = new MyPrintJobListener();
    DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
    pj.addPrintJobListener(listener);

    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
    pj.print(doc, null);


    }
```

**Edit 1:**

Ya me funcionan los eventos del Listener! 
Cuando tengo DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE, no me funcionan los eventos pero imprime (no todos los caracteres especiales).

Cuando especifico otro p.e. DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.CHAR_ARRAY.TEXT_PLAIN, no imprime, pero funcionan los eventos.

¿Alguien puede aclararme que ocurre? Es una impresora de tiquets tm-t20II por si necesitan saberlo.

Comment: Interesante pregunta, pero nos falta información para poder responderla. Si editas tu pregunta con un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) será mucho más facil ayudarte.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos gracias por comentar. Pregunta editada.

Answer (score 0):

La causa de por qué no funciona es la siguiente, no hay un terminador, por lo tanto no termina oficialmente.

Tal vez hayas oído de algunos caracteres de escape comunes, como `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, no todos los caracteres de escape son visibles en la consola, las cadenas tienen por ejemplo al final un `\0` que normalmente se le conoce como terminador de cadena y en el caso de la impresión se usa `\f` que es conocido si no mal recuerdo como *form feed* para mandar a la siguiente hoja, incluso para el terminador de archivos existe algo que se conoce como caracter de fin de archivo o `EOF`.

No todas las impresoras funciona igual, algunas esperan un caracter de escape especial, aunque a veces basta con un `EOF`.

Para evitarnos lidiar con toda esta complejidad entre sistemas operativos y vendedores de hardware Java creó la interfaz `Printable` con la intención de que sea usada en un `PrintJob`.

Una cosa que a muchos se nos olvida al iniciar es indicarle a nuestro `PrintJob` que ya no hay más páginas, es decir que ya terminamos y le estamos mandando ese terminador especial, en Java tenemos para ello la constante `java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE`.

```
public class MiPrintable implements Printable 
{
   public int print (Graphics g, PageFormat f, int pageIndex) 
   {
      if (pageIndex == 0) 
      {
         // Imprime "Hola mundo" en la primera pagina, en la posicion 100,100
         g.drawString("Hola mundo", 100,100);
         return PAGE_EXISTS;
      }
      else
         return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
   }
}
```

Puede parecer que no está relacionado este código, pero si nunca le indicamos al manejador de la tarea de impresión que la impresión ha conclido, el escucha nunca podrá saber si la impresión ya ha terminado.

Así como los flags del código, existen muchos más, revisa la clase `java.awt.print.Printable` para saber que banderas desatan que estados de tu escucha.